# Is there an inbuilt function to expand ipv6 addresses?

Tags: go, networking, ipv6

I'm working on a project where I need to expand IPv6 addresses. Is there an inbuilt function in Go?

What I'm currently doing is

```
ipv6 := "fe80:01::af0"
addr := net.ParseIP(ipv6)
fmt.Println(addr.String())
```

but this still prints

```
fe80:01::af0
```

What I actually need is

```
fe80:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0af0
```

Comment: It should be trivial to write your own formatter for a `net.IP` value.  But why? What requires a full IPv6 address? This seems like an unusual requirement.

Comment: Its an internal API which requires a full expanded ipv6 address, thats really annoying

Comment: Sounds like a buggy API :) But even so, it should be easy to print a `[]byte` in the format you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard library to do this, but it's easy to write your own function. One possible approach (of many):

```
func FullIPv6(ip net.IP) string {
    dst := make([]byte, hex.EncodedLen(len(ip)))
    _ = hex.Encode(dst, ip)
    return string(dst[0:4]) + ":" +
        string(dst[4:8]) + ":" +
        string(dst[8:12]) + ":" +
        string(dst[12:16]) + ":" +
        string(dst[16:20]) + ":" +
        string(dst[20:24]) + ":" +
        string(dst[24:28]) + ":" +
        string(dst[28:])
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ov5ESWCopND)

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect :)

Comment: Make sure to add checks or only ever use this with v6 IPs. If this is fed a v4 IP it will panic due to out-of-bounds.

Comment: @Adrian jep, im checking this by using `addr.To16() != nil`

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func expandIPv6Addr(s string) (string, error) {
    addr := net.ParseIP(s).To16()
    if addr == nil {
        return "", ErrInvalidAddress
    }

    var hex [16 * 3]byte
    for i := 0; i < len(addr); i++ {
        if i > 0 {
            hex[3*i-1] = ':'
        }
        hex[3*i] = nibbleToChar(addr[i] >> 4)
        hex[3*i+1] = nibbleToChar(addr[i])
    }

    return string(hex[:]), nil
}

func nibbleToChar(b byte) byte {
    b &= 0x0f
    if b > 9 {
        return ('a' - 10) + b
    }
    return '0' + b
}

var ErrInvalidAddress = errors.New("invalid address")

func main() {
    ipv6 := "fe80:01::af0"

    fmt.Println(ipv6)
    fmt.Println(expandIPv6Addr(ipv6))
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/2pWohnYHcal).

Answer (score 0):

The [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can do this with one line of code. Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
fmt.Print(ipaddr.NewIPAddressString("fe80:01::af0").GetAddress().ToFullString())
```

Output:

```
fe80:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0af0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a standard library way to expand IPv6 addresses via [netip.Addr.StringExpanded](https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip#Addr.StringExpanded), e.g.:

```
import "net/netip"

addr, _ := netip.ParseAddr("2001:db8::50")
fmt.Println(addr.StringExpanded())

# prints: 
2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0050
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/GsPG3Pmi-iO)